# 'ReactDOM' is not defined when I use webpack.ProvidePlugin() with ESlint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

I have a React app using **webpack+eslint+react**.

I use **webpack.ProvidePlugin()** instead of importing **ReactDOM** everywhere.

However, the **eslint** doesn't consider the **ReactDOM** is defined.

[image]

Here is my code:

**Webpack.config.js**

[image]

**ESlint**

[image]

**App.js**

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution is to add it to your [`.eslintrc` globals](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals):

```
{
    "globals": {
        "ReactDOM": true
    }
}
```

In general I think it's better to explicitly have imports and avoid using that plugin.

Comment: @Daniel this worked for me. I had to restart the server though. I put in: 
`"ReactDOM": true, "React": true` and the error has gone away

Comment: but it still shows that React is not defined in jsx?

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm using this with webpack ProvidePlugin.